# Clicking on button that leads to pop-up Java Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to write a program that opens the link, clicks the contribute button and then clicks the give button. However, when you actually click on the contribute button it opens a pop-up and my program is failing to do anything when the Contribute button is clicked. How can I go about clicking both buttons?

```
package com.demo.testcases;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class FirstClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    String giving = "https://givingday.northeastern.edu/campaigns/club-sports-3";

    driver.get(giving);

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("CONTRIBUTE")).click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("GIVE")).click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question the button with text as **GIVE** is a `<button>` tag so invoking `By.linkText()` will not work. You can use either of the following *Locator Strategy* along with _WebDriverWait_to click on the element :

- `cssSelector` :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.vote_modal_redirect_btn.btn-primary "))).click();
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='vote_modal_redirect_btn btn-primary' and contains(.,'Give')]"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Contribute button,it opens the popup window so please do the **following actions** :

1. use **getWindowHandles** method and **switch to the pop up window**.
2. Once you are switched to pop up window perform the desired action (accept it or close it).
3. Come back to the original / main window by using the window Handle.
4. Now perform the next operations.

Sample Code for winodw Handling :

```
   // Store and Print the name of all the windows open                

        Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

        System.out.println(handles);

        // Pass a window handle to the other window

        for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

            System.out.println(handle1);

            driver.switchTo().window(handle1);

            }
```